# NPM doesn't install dependencies that need build

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

*My `package.json` file looks like the following :*

```
{
  "name": "anna-backend",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "Backend for ANNA intranet",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": "IpsaOne DevTeam",
  "private": true,
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "mmmagic": "^0.4.6",
    [...]
  }
}
```

When I run `npm install` in the folder, **everything installs well except the dependencies that require building via `node-gyp`** (like bcrypt, mmmagic) and I have to install them manually by typing `npm install mmmagic`. Otherwise, they're just not installed and my application doesn't start.

**Is it expected behaviour ? Can I do anything about it ?**

Comment: As the node-gyp is required at npm install time, I think you have to install it globally with `npm install -g node-gyp`

Comment: In the install script, this is already done. Also, there is no error message (I would have included it)

Answer (score 0):

`mmmagic` module has issues on install 
https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic/issues/111

try install at last version `0.5.0`

Comment: This is not a problem only to the `mmmagic` package, `bcrypt` also doesn't install correctly. Although you are right, I will try to update them :)